# Daily tag email has a link to a google drive document

Tags: support, email

The daily email I receive regarding new Python questions on SO arrived today and had a link to a google drive document called "banana_features.csv". I've never seen this email come with a link/attachment before and it just seems odd...

Not sure if this is a bug SE side or some artefact of the content of the digest doing it... any clues?

Screen shot of the first 20 rows if it's of any use:

[image]

Comment: That's bananas. Can you forward the email to me, please? adam@stackoverflow

Comment: @Adam it's on its way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Called it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435530/how-to-make-the-svm-direct-predict) includes a plain Google Drive link and Gmail tries to get clever by thinking those are attachments.

Comment: Heh... was just commenting to say that re-reading the email I've just noticed that... sorry 'bout that - long day and tired eyes! Wonder if it'll be possible to smuggle spammy links into posts like that...

Comment: @JonClements No worries. And hey, don't give spammers ideas...